# insert/select из временной таблицы

Tags: sql

Задача: есть 100 записей в таблице (рейтинг по баллам). Нужно вывести 7 записей с баллами, где 4 строка - это usr_id в селекте, 1 2 3 - записи, в которых больше баллов чем у 4 строки и 5 6 7 записи, где баллов меньше, чем у 4 строки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В отчет нужно вывести, выделенное рамкой, отталкиваясь от 13 строки.
Пробую сделать отчет, используя временную таблицу, но ничего не выходит (при селекте идет ошибка).

```
declare rn decimal(10)

DECLARE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE table1 (point_group varchar(10), 
point_code varchar(10), point_name varchar(10), 
USR_ID varchar(10, fio varchar(10), ball int, zball int, rn int)

begin

insert into table1
select point_group, point_code, point_name, USR_ID, FIO, BALL, ZBALL, rownum() over (order by ball desc) as rn
from a3_user_rating_new01

select rn = rn from table1 where USR_ID = 371
select * from table1 where rn between (rn-3) and (rn+3)
```

Текст ошибки:
Error starting at line : 45 in command -
declare rn decimal(10)

DECLARE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE table1 (point_group varchar(10), 
point_code varchar(10), point_name varchar(10), 
USR_ID varchar(10, fio varchar(10), ball int, zball int, rn int)

begin

insert into table1
select point_group, point_code, point_name, USR_ID, FIO, BALL, ZBALL, rownum() over (order by ball desc) as rn
from a3_user_rating_new01

select rn = rn from table1 where USR_ID = 371
select * from table1 where rn between (rn-3) and (rn+3)
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 3, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following:

:= ; not null default character
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: текст ошибки, вероятно, тоже не помешало бы привести.

Comment: Вот эта строка `select rn = rn from table1 where USR_ID = 371` скорее всего должна быть такой `select rn into rn from table1 where USR_ID = 371`. А вообще лучше приведите данные, не верю, что тут нужна временная таблица

Comment: Добавил описание таблицы на скриншоте и желаемый результат. Судя по ошибке, ошибка возникает уже на 3 строке, где я объявляю временную таблицу. С радостью выслушаю иные решения :)

Comment: что то я не видел что бы таблицы делались как declare, может create хотя я временные не пробовал делать хз как оно работает ... Но мне кажется что в оракле их на постоянно объявляют такие таблицы один раз, просто на начало любой транзакции они для нее пусты и после commit/rollback все что в них было теряется, как то так. А запрос сейчас попробую сделать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой вариант:

```
select * from (
  select a.*,rownum N,
         max(decode(usr_id,371,rownum,0)) over() M
    from
     (select *
        from table1
       order by ball desc
     ) a
 ) where n between M-3 and M+3
```

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @VyacheslavGroshenkov Немного ошибся, rank() надо заменить на row_number(), иначе будет больше строк в случае повторяющихся ball